# Any issues talking with Java communicating with Active Directory over JNDI/LDAP/TLS due to BEAST fixes?

Tags: java, ssl, active-directory, beast

Both Microsoft and Java have made changes in order to address the BEAST vulnerability. Based on [this MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2012/01/19/patch-available-for-sql-server-and-java-6-update-30.aspx), it looks like some interoperability issues have crept up, Microsoft has apparently provided a SQL Server patch to help out with interoperability with Java 6 update 30 and later.

Since the BEAST issue was related to the TLS protocol, I would think that similar interoperability issues could creep up with with Java code that tries to talk TLS with Windows systems. So...

- Does anyone know about any similar interoperability issues that have occurred with Java code running on Java 6 update 29 or later that tries to communicate with Active Directory via JNDI, LDAP, and TLS?
- Anyone have an idea why Microsoft's interoperability patch appears to be for SQL Server and not Windows?